# Mysql, insert if all columns don't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

I have a table with 3 columns. None of the columns are unique key.

I want to run an insert only if a row doesn't exists already with the exact same values in each column.

```
given the following table:
a   b   c
----------
1   3   5
7   1   3
9   49  4

a=3 b=4 c=3    should insert
a=7 b=1 c=3    should not insert (a row with these exact values exists)
```

The solutions I have found so far need a unique primary key.

Comment: So define a composite `UNIQUE` key over `(a,b,c)`?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is adding a **UNIQUE KEY** to your table. You can also make an algorithm for comparing the values but you do not want to do that if you have many columns in your table.

Comment: Yes, you just have to make an algorithm of comparing the unique key of the existing record and the new record.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. All 3 columns are equally important, not just one. The data I'm storing makes it so one column can't be unique. Currently (using java) I'm doing 2 separate queries, one is a select (where all 3 columns = x,y,z) then only doing the insert if that returns 0 results. I'm looking to do this in one mysql query so we don't have to hit it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I get your point correctly. But hope this help.

First of all you have to SELECT the row with WHERE clause

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a=$a && b=$b && c=$c
```

After that you fetch_array or fetch_row if the array or row exist, that means 'not insert'.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this all needs to be done in the SQL query itself and not using php like you suggested or java in my case.